# Can’t send email – postfix/sendmail error referring to command line

Tags: php, postfix, sendmail

I have a PHP script under a Wordpress theme sending emails using the `mail()` function. 
I have `postfix`, `dovecot` and `sendmail` installed on the server.

Mails are not being sent from that script. 
After a long wide search, the only lead I could find as to this error is this `mail.log` error I am getting from the php `mail()` execution:

`postfix/sendmail[7588]: fatal: Recipient addresses must be specified on the command line or via the -t option`

I couldn't find any info as how to deal with it. 
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Took me a few days but here's the solution:

It's in the mail section of `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
These configurations need to look like this:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Comment: Five years later, this solved my problem.  Thanks!